# How to set a max height on Bootstrap Modal Image in vh?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport-units

Is it possible to set the maximum height of an Image in Bootstrap modal in vh units and the Modal width adjusted to fit the image width?

```
<div id='mymodal'>
<div class="modal-header">...</div>
<div id="myModalBody" class="modal-body">
<img src="/Imgs/someimg.jpg" title="sometitle" class="img-rounded img-responsive img-full" alt="somealt" />
<p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">... </div>
<div>
#mymodal img{
max-height: 90vh;
}
```

Comment: Check [this] out. I think that it could get you started.

Comment: @MasterAM there is no link.

Comment: [oh, snap](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units), I guess `ctrl+z` did more than I intended...

Comment: @MasterAM I have read your post but there is nothing about Bootstrap modal :(